# Encoding of the AuthzSVNAccessFile

Tags: svn, apache

I have a repository containing paths with non-ASCII characters (latin1)

I am having problems with authorization file containing those paths.

Do you know which encoding should be the AuthzSVNAccessFile?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking through the subversion source it seems you should use utf-8 as the encoding of the authz file.